# Xamarin.iOS及びXamarin.AndroidのclassをPCLから参照する方法

Tags: ios, android, c#, xamarin

Xamarin.iOSとXamarin.Androidにそれぞれ機能が同じclassが実装されています。
このclassは各デバイスの特性に応じて若干実装方法は異なっております。
これらclassをPCLから参照し、instance生成を行おうと思っております。

しかし、実装及びcompile時に上記classのありかが見つからないとの理由で
エラーになります。
PCLの各リソースをXamarin.iOS及びXamarin.Androidのリソースから
参照することができますが、この逆はできないのでしょうか？
もしご存知でしたら、ご教授のほどお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

こちら、

- [C# - C# Xamarin.FormsのDependencyServiceの代替え(36951)｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/36951)

の回答が参考になるかと思います。

が、この方法は「インスタンスの生成は Android または iOS 側で行わせ、生成されたインスタンスの共通なインターフェースを PCL 側で使用する」というものであるため、

> これらclassをPCLから参照し、instance生成を行おうと思っております

の目的とは合わないかも知れません。
（厳密には、PCL側から、各プラットフォーム側にあるクラスのインスタンス生成を行うことは不可能です。）

上記以外の方法としては、「Bait and Switch」と呼ばれるテクニックがあります。

これは、全く同じ名称のアセンブリ(DLLファイル名)・クラスを、PCLプロジェクトから参照する用と、Androidプロジェクトから参照する用、iOSプロジェクトから参照する用に３つ用意し、

1. PCLプロジェクトから参照する用は何も実装しない
2. Androidプロジェクトから参照する用はAndroid固有の実装を行う
3. iOSプロジェクトから参照する用はiOS固有の実装を行う

とし、PCLプロジェクトは１.を、Androidプロジェクトには２．を、iOSプロジェクトには3.を参照設定します。

すると、Androidアプリとして実行するときは2.で実装したクラスが使われ、iOSアプリとして実行するときは３．が使用されるため、「見かけ上」、各プラットフォーム固有の実装がPCLから呼び出せているように見えます。

このテクニックに関しては、以下のリンクが詳しいので、参考にしてください。

- [Plugins for Xamarinを作ろう！ - ぴーさんログ](http://ticktack.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/04/08/180321)
- [共有コードからネイティブ依存処理が使える！PCLを使ったXamarinライブラリ作成テクニック (フェンリル | デベロッパーズブログ)](http://blog.fenrir-inc.com/jp/2015/12/xamarin_plugin.html)